# Published api to IIS 10 does not reflect latest code

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASp.NET web api running on an IIS (v10) server.

In my development environment a particular endpoint returns all of the rows in a MySQL database table as expected (both in Swagger and the client UI).

After publishing the api and updating the server with the newly published folder (and recycling the application pool) the same endpoint returns an error complaining that a string cannot be recognized as a DateTime: *String '14/12/2021' was not recognized as a valid DateTime*.  I get the same error if I point the development front end to the deployed api.  Both development and deployed apis use the same database connection string (the solution is not yet live).

Changes were made some time ago to the table in question that replaced a DateTime field with a varchar field to store a string representation of a date.

I have cleaned and rebuilt the api project to no effect.

The other endpoints in the deployed api work as expected.

Any ideas on what may be causing the deployed api to not reflect the latest version of the code?

Comment: Check what format your app is expecting date times in , if 14/12/2021 is failing then it's probably expecting US date format of mm/dd/yyyy which of course will fail as there isn't a 14th month.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing your date it's likely it's trying to parse it as an american date e.g MM/DD/YYYY so since there's not a 14th month it's failing.

If you're looking at a dd/mm/yyyy format then look at doing:

```
using System.Globalization;

DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(theDateVariable, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
```

or

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(theDateVariable, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

So it's not that the code changes aren't reflected it's that the code is broken hence the "String '14/12/2021' was not recognized as a valid DateTime." error.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The solution handles the date - string conversion as expected in the development environment.  When publishes and deployed to a remote IIS server (using the same database as dev) the error is thrown.  It's this that leads me to believe that there is something awry with the deployment to the remote IIS machine

Comment: It's more likely that the default culture on the server is US rather than your local development environment/server which is in the correct culture.